# How capture a window that is opened inside of a “new desktop environment”?

Tags: delphi, screenshot

Good afternoon to all.

I want see a window that is open inside of a "new desktop environment", from of my remote assistance tool, but I'm not able to see this window using conventional functions like this below:

```
    function RandomPassword(PLen: Integer): string;
    var
      str: string;
    begin
      Randomize;
      str    := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
      Result := '';
      repeat
        Result := Result + str[Random(Length(str)) + 1];
      until (Length(Result) = PLen)
    end;

        procedure Printscreen;
        var
          DCDesk: HDC;
          bmp: TBitmap;
          hmod, hmod2 : HMODULE;
          BitBltAPI: function(DestDC: HDC; X, Y, Width, Height: Integer; SrcDC: HDC; XSrc, YSrc: Integer; Rop: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
          GetWindowDCAPI: function(hWnd: HWND): HDC; stdcall;

          begin

         hmod := GetModuleHandle('Gdi32.dll');
         hmod2:= GetModuleHandle('User32.dll');

         if (hmod <> 0) and (hmod2 <> 0) then begin

          bmp := TBitmap.Create;

          bmp.Height := Screen.Height;
          bmp.Width := Screen.Width;

          GetWindowDCAPI:= GetProcAddress(hmod2, 'GetWindowDC');

          if (@GetWindowDCAPI <> nil) then begin

            DCDesk := GetWindowDCAPI(GetDesktopWindow);

          end;

          BitBltAPI:= GetProcAddress(hmod, 'BitBlt');

          if (@BitBltAPI <> nil) then begin

            BitBltAPI(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height, DCDesk, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            bmp.SaveToFile('ScreenShot_------_' + RandomPassword(8) + '.bmp');

          end;

            ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, DCDesk);

            bmp.Free;

            FreeLibrary(hmod);
            FreeLibrary(hmod2);

         end;
        end;

begin
   while True do
    begin
       Printscreen;
      Sleep(5000);
    end;

end.
```

That produces [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSlcv.png)

Already using Team View software for example, the window appears on screen capture normally and produces [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4bYX.jpg).

So, exist some way for see this window in screen capture like is possible from of Team View software?

All suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: Call Randomize exactly once in the life of your program or you will get some nasty surprises. Try calling RandomPassword in a loop.

Comment: [This is the app that open this window](https://www.itau.com.br/computador/)

Comment: "graphics" already uses "windows", you won't gain anything by not using declared functions in "windows".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to get the screenshot of a *secure* desktop.  If that is the case first you must read the documentation about [this topic.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) Because **this is not a trivial task** (you must know about [Sessions, Desktops and Windows Stations](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/)). Also your application must be a [trusted process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uac/2006/05/03/user-account-control-prompts-on-the-secure-desktop/) running from the *Local SYSTEM* Account.

From here now you must do this.

- Select the proper Input WinStation ([`OpenWindowStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684339(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetProcessWindowStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683225(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SetProcessWindowStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686232(v=vs.85).aspx))
- Switch to the active (secure) desktop ([`OpenInputDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684309(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetThreadDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683232(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SetThreadDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250(v=vs.85).aspx))
- Finally use the [`BitBlt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx) to capture the screen.

Recommended Lecture

- [Sessions, Desktops and Windows Stations](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/)
- [MSDN Desktops reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: you is right, I will go to study about this. But if someone (or youself) want put here some fragmento de código, for help understand better about this.

Comment: You must try to write the code and then go back with a new question if you found a problem. But first start reading the docs.

Comment: with reference to my code above and explanation of all doc that you suggested above, is possible get screenshots just  of `Session 0` with this my code make, is right?

Comment: The current code is not able to work properly  because you have several flaws, first you must trap the exceptions and protect the system resources using `try..finally` and `try..except` blocks.  Also you must move you screen capture code to  a secondary thread, because you must call the `SetThreadDesktop`  method to switch to the active desktop and capture the screen.

Comment: Based in all that you said, I found [this relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780593/why-the-screenshot-doesnt-work-black-screen) here in S.O. This will help me so much, mostly in dll injection process.

Comment: Dll injection.. Then why do you care taking a screen shot from a different desktop? The code will run in the process that created that desktop. I guess you haven't yet decided in what way you'd access card information.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, this process that create this Winstation is protected against dll injection :-(. So as suggested on last answer in relevant question that I showed before, for this capture works fine in WinSta0, will be necessary make a dll injection in a process that can run like trusted, eg: cmd.exe