# How can I execute Notepad using IIS hosted WCF?

Tags: wcf, iis

I'm using the below code in my WCF service to execute Notepad:

```
 public void ExecuteApp()
    {
       Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        p.Start();
    }
```

and I call it from a remote machine but nothing happens in the WCF hosted machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session 0 Isolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466962/session-0-isolation)

Comment: Learn about session isolation, and you can easily see why.

Comment: Curious to know what could be usecase which requires notepad to be opened using WCF service and who will write into it when its open?